# Rails Error: undefined method ` ' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, cart, nomethoderror

So, since I'm fairly new to rails (and ruby), I'm still trying to understand *where* it all goes wrong here. I'm working on a cart in a webshop. The user gets a Session where his cart items (In this case line_item.rb) is stored.

**Problem:** 
When I click an item, it gets added to the cart via the cart method add_product. If you click on the same item again, instead of adding the same item twice, it should simply then ++1 to the quantity-property of that item. But, when I click it the second time i get the error page saying:

**NoMethodError in LineItemsController#create**

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my cart.rb:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
      Rails.logger.debug(current_item.quantity)
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

The quantity property for line_item is of type integer. Should be able to add integers to it, right? Thats where I'm confused at the moment.

Here is the "create" method in line_items_controller.rb:

```
  def create
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
@line_item.product = product

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
      notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @line_item,
      status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
      status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Any Ideas?

Cheers

Comment: The error message should indicate which line it is failing on. Since the error message is `NoMethodError in LineItemsController#create`, I am guessing it has to be with a line in the `create` method, and not in the `Cart#add_product` as you are mentioning.

Comment: Where is your find_by_product_id method defined? current_item is not getting a value.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy well here it is:
app/models/cart.rb:7:in `add_product'
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:45:in `create'

I'm staring at it but can't understand what is wrong.

@ctilley79 I thought that method is part of the finder methods of the rails frame work. Can any one confirm this?

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that exists after messing with a project of mine.  I've obviously never needed it.

Comment: put a log statement and try to print out product on line 3 of your controller.  I had an issue where the syntax for the params[:product_id] was incorrect.  If that's the case try something like params[]["product_id"].  I'm fairly confident this is it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because current_item doesn't have any quantity. 
There's probably no default value. You're expecting it to be 0, but it's actually `nil`.

I set a default value, and make sure that column can't be nil. Also, you can define a `before_create` method that would set that value to 0 before saving (if it's nil).

Another way to fix this would be making sure you don't have a nil there:

```
current_item.quantity = current_item.quantity.blank? ? 1 : current_item.quantity + 1
```

Comment: Wow... yep, that fixes it. Although, I should of course make sure the default value is 1. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This says that current_item.quantity is null. This can be Integer but stored as null in database.
If this, you can set one value by default (in migration), or when you create for first time you can set the quantity value to 1.